# How to use $lookup with a nested array as localField

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a two collections like this:

**Collection Countries:**

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "London", "fruits": [1, 2]},
            {"city": "Birmingham", "fruits": [2]},
        ],
    },
    {
        "country": "DE",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "Munich", "fruits": [2, 3]},
            {"city": "Berlin", "fruits": [1, 2, 3]},
        ],
    },
]
```

**Collection Fruits:**

```
 [
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "name": "banana",
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "name": "kiwi",
    },
    {
        "uid": 3,
        "name": "mango",
    },
]
```

**GOAL:**

Using the mongo aggregation framework, i want to replace in the $project stage the list of uids at `shops.fruits` in the the collection "Countries" with the actual documents from the collection fruits. The uid in the documents of the collection Fruits is a custom field and separate from the mongo _id field.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried the following pipeline

```
pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {},
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "fruits",
      localField: "shops.fruits",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "shops.fruits",
    },
  },
];
```

**ISSUE:**

Unfortunately, this returns for each document in Countries only the first shop with the documents from Fruits, but not for the whole array of shops.

**Actual outcome:**

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "shops": {
            "city": "London",
            "fruits": [
                {
                    "uid": 1,
                    "name": "banana",
                },
                {
                    "uid": 2,
                    "name": "kiwi",
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    // ...
]
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "shops": [
            {
                "city": "London",
                "fruits": [
                    {
                        "uid": 1,
                        "name": "banana",
                    },
                    {
                        "uid": 2,
                        "name": "kiwi",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                "city": "Birmingham",
                "fruits": [
                    {
                        "uid": 2,
                        "name": "kiwi",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    // ...
    
]
```

**QUESTION:**

How can i use $lookup with a nested array as localField ([without an $unwind stage if possible](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array))?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just $unwind, do the $lookup and re group like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNiehJy08aj)?

Comment: there is no way without the $unwind and then $group again stages?

Comment: anything specific that you don't prefer this solution? Actually in MongoDB, the recommended way would be you simply denormalize the the fruit documents in the countries collection, so you don't need to do the $lookup at all

Comment: you mean to have the fruits as embedded documents? the issue is that i need to use this fruits collection in multiple other collections. this is why i decided to keep them separate and just link an id. When I need to rename the name of a fruit (or add another property to the fruit object) this would get quite complex to maintain as embedded documents, right?

Comment: yep. Your use case of normalizing fruits as standalone collection make senses to me. Just for now you will need to stick with unwind-lookup-group strategy. Or you can still refactor the `countries` collection to shop level like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xo3JccxLZ6W) to have 1 plain lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *"populate"* the `"fruits"` array in `countries` collection documents with the info from the `fruits` collection without using `"$unwind"`/`"$group"`, but it's less straightforward.  Here's one way you could do it.

N.B.:  This aggregation pipeline does not consider the possibility that a `"fruits"` `uid` does not exist in the `fruits` collection.  It is also possible that the output `"fruits"` array will be reordered.

```js
db.countries.aggregate([
  { // get all the fruits for this doc
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "fruits",
      "localField": "shops.fruits",
      "foreignField": "uid",
      "as": "theFruits",
      "pipeline": [
        { // don't want _id
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      // rewrite shops array
      "shops": {
        // transform each element of shops
        "$map": {
          "input": "$shops",
          "as": "shop",
          "in": {
            // keep everything in object ...
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$shop",
              // ... and rewrite fruits array
              {
                "fruits": {
                  // keep all fruits that match for this city
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$theFruits",
                    "as": "theFruit",
                    "cond": {
                      "$in": ["$$theFruit.uid", "$$shop.fruits"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // don't want/need this anymore
    "$unset": "theFruits"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ulh62iNB73_).